# Create dynamic pivot list using joins

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I want to create dynamic pivot list on list which has data in below format

```
"products" : 
    {
        "name": "ABC",       
        "Variance": [
                    {
                        "Date": "01-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "02-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "11"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "03-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "12"
                    },
            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "XYZ",       
        "Variance": [
                    {
                        "Date": "01-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "03-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "24"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "04-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "28"
                    },
            ],


    },
    {
        "name": "PQR",       
        "Variance": [
                    {
                        "Date": "01-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "20"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "02-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "04-01-2018",                
                        "Value": "24"
                    },
            ],
    }
```

I want to create pivot list so it can return data like

```
"NewProducts":[{
        "Date": "01-01-2018", 
        "ABC" : "10"
        "XYZ" : "22",
        "PQR" : "20"
    },
    {
        "Date": "02-01-2018", 
        "ABC" : "11"
        "XYZ" : "null",
        "PQR" : "22"
    },
    {
        "Date": "03-01-2018", 
        "ABC" : "12"
        "XYZ" : "24",
        "PQR" : "null"
    },
    {
        "Date": "04-01-2018", 
        "ABC" : "null"
        "XYZ" : "28",
        "PQR" : "24"
    }]
```

I tried some approach of having joins on inner lists, but not getting required results. I want to avoid loops as my product list will vary as per selections.
I was able to join the list using for loops, but I want to have minimal use of for loops. Any suggestions would be really helpful to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your sample data isn't a valid C# data structure - how are you storing the data originally, how do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use a `Dictionary<string,int>` to hold the dynamic value pairs, you can use LINQ by first flattening the nested structure into a new flat list with `SelectMany` and then grouping by `Date`:

```
var ans = products.SelectMany(p => p.Variance.Select(v => new { p.name, v.Date, v.Value }))
                  .GroupBy(pv => pv.Date)
                  .Select(pvg => new { Date = pvg.Key, Fields = pvg.ToDictionary(p => p.name, p => p.Value) });
```